# Get video length in hours:minutes:seconds round result to second

Tags: command-line, video

Right now I am using the following command to get the output of a videos duration

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -sexagesimal 'video file.mp4'
```

The result is **0:33:29.410000**

I need this result changed with the following

- An additional 0 must be at the front 0:33:29.410000
- The seconds must be rounded up or down. The final output should be **00:33:29**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$1,$2,$3}'
```

or if you want to check the format before conversion to prevent errors:

```
awk -F: '/^[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/ {printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$1,$2,$3}'
```

---

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -sexagesimal 'video file.mp4' | awk -F: '{printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$1,$2,$3}'
00:33:29
```